# Compiling third-party applications

Tags: discussion, scope

Is asking questions about customizing the compilation process of third-party, open source applications on topic here? If it's not on topic here, is it on topic anywhere else?

I modified a patch for Solr (Apache v2.0 license), I have it working, and I can successfully compile and package it. However I want to customize the version to indicate that it's not vanilla Solr. I don't know where that setting is, and I haven't been able to find it. Could I ask such a question on Stack Overflow or any other Stack Exchange site?

Comment: While I don't *necessarily* see a problem with that, there's a couple of outstanding issues:  does the license of Nginx permit you to do that?  Does their documentation not specify where the version number is set?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I'd be surprised if you couldn't find the appropriate way to change the version strong with a few minutes of digging through the code.

Comment: @Makoto I used Nginx as an example. My actual use case is Solr which is Apache v2 licensed. I've searched the documentation and build configuration files, but I can't seem to find the right setting that I'm looking for. However, I'm uncertain if this sort of question is on topic here.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I've looked though the ant build configurations, but I haven't been able to find the actual version setting used.