# Question about building FFMPEG closed as not about programming or software development

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, close-reasons

For hours I had been trying to build the [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) library to incorporate it in my project for audio processing, but I just couldn't get it to work.

I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76941812/building-ffmpeg-on-windows-with-msys-2-0-mingw-64-always-fails) for help on the main site, but it was closed as not about programming or software development. Can someone explain to me how is that not about programming or software development?

The building process involves compiling C code and the problem is that the compilation process is failing for unknown reason.

If that question does not belong on Stack Overflow, where does it belong on?

Comment: I voted to close the question as it seemed like a better fit on a different Exchange site, such as [Video.SE] or SuperUser (NOTE: I am not a SME (Subject Matter Expert)

Comment: At _least_ with the information given here that you're trying to build the ffmpeg _library_ to use in a software project, it's definitely on-topic.  Even otherwise, it's [probably still on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298581/208273).  I've edited based on the info here and reopened it.

Comment: @RyanM i do want to use it in a programming project, yes.

Comment: A cross-site duplicate: *[Questions about building software](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161451/questions-about-building-software)*. Though there is probably a more canonical question somewhere.

Comment: Related (not duplicates): *[Compiling third-party applications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291734/compiling-third-party-applications)* and *[If I find a repository that I cannot get to run with the readme.txt instructions, what is appropriate Stack Exchange community to post my question in?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397340/if-i-find-a-repository-that-i-cannot-get-to-run-with-the-readme-txt-instructions)*

Comment: Now the question has two votes to close for "debugging details". I wonder what that means considering that OP does have the steps to reproduce.

Comment: I'm getting kind of annoyed honestly. I've been willing to accept that SO decided questions about dev tools are on topic. But now we've reached the point where we're apparently supposed to accept "Q. How do I avoid a problem with compiling someone else's code? A. This is caused by a bug in one of the dependencies; try upgrading to this patch version", simply because "someone else's code" happens to be a library that could be used from one's own code (and the question isn't about *using* the code as a library). That's well beyond my understanding of what SO *should* be about.